# setBitmap not working after the recent SDK update on Android studio (android Oreo)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I was using setBitmap to set wallpaper of the device. But recently I update my android studio and after the update the **button** to "Set wallpaper" **isn't responding** and **no toast message** is appearing either, i don't know why. Please look into the code and tell me if I am doing some mistake or any changes can be made. Thank you.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(newString).into(imageView);

    try {
        final Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        setButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                try {
                    // Set the image as wallpaper
                    if (image != null) {
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(image);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No image was chosen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(new String(), e.toString());
    }
```

This is my current Build number and version of Android Studio

```
**Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0**
```

LogCat

```
11-28 20:02:13.810 2291-2291/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-28 20:02:14.482 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper-1/lib/arm
11-28 20:02:14.577 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-28 20:02:14.586 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-28 20:02:14.617 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
11-28 20:02:14.643 2291-2311/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
11-28 20:02:14.658 2291-2311/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
11-28 20:02:14.658 2291-2311/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
11-28 20:02:14.784 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
11-28 20:02:14.786 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-28 20:02:14.797 2291-2314/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11717
11-28 20:02:14.797 2291-2314/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
11-28 20:02:14.797 2291-2314/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                       adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper
11-28 20:02:14.932 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
11-28 20:02:14.933 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
11-28 20:02:14.944 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
11-28 20:02:14.967 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001e/n/armeabi-v7a
11-28 20:02:14.967 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001e/n/armeabi
11-28 20:02:15.048 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-28 20:02:15.050 2291-2318/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/System.out: [socket][0] connection wallpaper-a7fb7.firebaseio.com/2600:1901:0:94b6:::443;LocalPort=-1(0)

                                                                             [ 11-28 20:02:15.050  2291: 2318 D/         ]
                                                                             [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper :443 
11-28 20:02:15.096 2291-2306/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Enter while loop.
11-28 20:02:15.220 2291-2318/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/System.out: [socket][/2402:3a80:503:3d25:0:3e:60f7:ff01:51026] connected
11-28 20:02:15.340 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001c/n/armeabi-v7a
11-28 20:02:15.340 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000001c/n/armeabi
11-28 20:02:15.403 2291-2337/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
11-28 20:02:15.551 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/Ads: Starting ad request.
11-28 20:02:15.556 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("80037727BB6D827763FEF5179F1559A9") to get test ads on this device.
11-28 20:02:15.598 2291-2314/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
11-28 20:02:15.648 2291-2306/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Enter while loop.
11-28 20:02:15.687 2291-2345/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 62.0.3202.84 (code 320208402)
11-28 20:02:15.788 2291-2345/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 21 ms (timestamps 4184-4205)
11-28 20:02:15.796 2291-2346/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/art: Before Android 4.1, method double java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextDouble(double, double) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
11-28 20:02:15.796 2291-2346/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextInt(int, int) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
11-28 20:02:15.796 2291-2346/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/art: Before Android 4.1, method long java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.internalNextLong(long, long) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in java.util.Random
11-28 20:02:15.805 2291-2345/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(46)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-28 20:02:15.806 2291-2345/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "62.0.3202.84", actual native library version number "62.0.3202.84"
11-28 20:02:15.913 2291-2306/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Enter while loop.
11-28 20:02:15.932 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-28 20:02:15.940 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/OpenGLRenderer: Get disable program binary service property (0)
11-28 20:02:15.940 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
11-28 20:02:15.942 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/ProgramBinary/Service: ProgramBinaryService client side disable debugging.
11-28 20:02:15.942 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/ProgramBinary/Service: ProgramBinaryService client side disable binary content debugging.
11-28 20:02:15.943 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 182828, program map length is 124.
11-28 20:02:15.944 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 86, and path is /dev/ashmem.
11-28 20:02:15.944 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(86).
11-28 20:02:15.950 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
11-28 20:02:15.998 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
11-28 20:02:16.141 2291-2380/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
11-28 20:02:16.144 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
11-28 20:02:16.219 2291-2318/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/System.out: gba_cipher_suite:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
11-28 20:02:17.549 2291-2306/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Enter while loop.
11-28 20:02:17.617 2291-2306/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Enter while loop.
11-28 20:02:22.358 2291-2300/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=14KB, data=30KB
11-28 20:02:22.360 2291-2300/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: After code cache collection, code=14KB, data=30KB
11-28 20:02:22.360 2291-2300/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
11-28 20:02:22.417 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/Ads: Starting ad request.
11-28 20:02:22.418 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("80037727BB6D827763FEF5179F1559A9") to get test ads on this device.
11-28 20:02:22.461 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/SettingsInterface: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
11-28 20:02:22.501 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/Ads: Starting ad request.
11-28 20:02:22.501 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("80037727BB6D827763FEF5179F1559A9") to get test ads on this device.
11-28 20:02:22.537 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/Ads: Starting ad request.
11-28 20:02:22.538 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("80037727BB6D827763FEF5179F1559A9") to get test ads on this device.
11-28 20:02:22.602 2291-2306/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Enter while loop.
11-28 20:02:22.618 2291-2349/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
11-28 20:02:22.644 2291-2402/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/System.out: [socket][1] connection firebasestorage.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4003:c03::5f:443;LocalPort=-1(15000)

                                                                             [ 11-28 20:02:22.644  2291: 2402 D/         ]
                                                                             [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper :443 
11-28 20:02:22.733 2291-2402/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/System.out: [socket][/2402:3a80:503:3d25:0:3e:60f7:ff01:59031] connected
11-28 20:02:22.922 2291-2402/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
11-28 20:02:22.923 2291-2402/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
11-28 20:02:23.014 2291-2380/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
11-28 20:02:23.014 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
11-28 20:02:23.027 2291-2309/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
11-28 20:02:23.028 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
11-28 20:02:23.240 2291-2309/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
11-28 20:02:23.240 2291-2291/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
11-28 20:02:24.238 2291-2306/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Enter while loop.
11-28 20:02:24.274 2291-2306/com.example.souravkumar.wallpaper I/art: Enter while loop.
```

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: @MironOphir I have updated the question with the logCat

Comment: This log doesn't show any exception. Are you sure your click listener code is executing? You can add a log line there to see if it uns when you click the button.